# ajax post calender controls in php not working :(

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am following a tutorial to make a calender, i have made the first bit of the calender but after adding more code to make buttons to go the the previous and next month it is no longer working :(

I get this error on ie

Webpage error details
Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
Line: 23
Char: 4
Code: 0

and it just shows processing instead of the calender.

Here is the code if anyone could take a look thatd be great

calendar_start.php - http://tinypic.com/r/sdo19t/6 (sorry i had to upload a pic as it would not let me space it 4 lines to make it code in all places).

show_calendar.php   (this is the file you should be able to view the calender on

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="calCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />



<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
showmonth = month;
showyear = year;
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showcalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>







<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function next_month(){
var nextmonth = showmonth + 1;
if (nextmonth > 12) {
   nextmonth = 1;
   showyear = showyear + 1;
 }
 showmonth = nextmonth;
 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showcalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>






<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function last_month(){

var lastmonth = showmonth - 1;
if (lastmonth < 1) {
   lastmonth = 12;
   showyear = showyear - 1;
 }
 showmonth = lastmonth;

 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showcalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>





</head>
<body onLoad="initialCalendar();">
<div id="showCalendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

calCss.css    (this is fine i think, as it worked before)

```
#calendar_wrap {
width: 924px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.title_bar {
width: 100%; 
height: 30px;
}
.previous_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: left;
}
.show_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
.next_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: right;
}
.week_days {
width: 100%;
}       
.days_of_the_week  {
float: left;
width: 14%;
text-align: center;
}      
.cal_day {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
width: 128px;
height: 95px;
background-color: #9C9;
}
.day_heading {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 40px;
height: 16px;
padding: 6px;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
}    
.openings {
width: 100%;
clear:left;
text-align: center;
}
.non_cal_day {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
width: 128px;
height: 95px;
background-color: #CCC;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Hopefully it is something simple, im very new at this, :)/:( it is not to do with the localhost

Comment: please try to narrow down the code in your question

Answer (score 0):

You almost found the error yourself. You posted this error message:

```
Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object Line: 23
```

So take a look at line 23.

Your div has an id = "showCalendar", and you're calling "showcalendar" (small c).

Remember, attribute IDs are case sensitive.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for that, i edited it but now its coming up with just the previous and next month buttons but the calender is not showing :( When i click next month thiss comes up      Webpage error details

Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
Line: 57
Char: 1
Code: 0

Comment: i have edited all the showCalendar to the same by the way but still get the same error